# Poisson process and probabilities

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution

> Let $\{X(t); t\ge 0\}$ be a Poisson process with rate $\lambda =2$. Find the probability $\Pr\{X(1)=1, X(2)=3\}$

And here is my solution:

As there is a Poisson process then the intervals are independent random variables thus $\Pr\{X(1)=1, X(2)=3\}$=$\Pr\{X(1)=1\}$$\Pr\{ X(2)=3\}$=$\frac{2e^{-2}}{1!} \frac{[2(2)]^3e^{-4}}{3!} =\frac{e^{-6}4^3}{3}$

But the book's answer is $4e^{-4}$. I don't see where is my mistake.
Can someone tell me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $s<t$, by the definition of Poisson Process, we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
P(X(t)=n,X(s)=n)&=&P(X(t)-X(s)=n-m,X(s)-X(0)=m-0)\\
& &\qquad\text{(introducing  increments)}\\
&=&P(X(t)-X(s)=n-m)\times P(X(s)-X(0)=m-0),\\
& &\qquad\text{(by ind. inc. prop.)}\\
&=&P(X(t-s)=n-m)\times P(X(s)=m)
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 2):

In a Poisson process the *increments*, not the values themselves, are independent. Thus the increment in the first time interval of length $1$ is $1$ while the increment in the second time interval of length $1$ is $2$.

Comment: So is this $\Pr\{X(1)=1, X(2)=3\}$=$\Pr\{X(1)=1\}$ $ \Pr\{ X(2)=3\}$ wrong?

Comment: Yes; $X (1) $ and $X (2) $ are not independent.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Write $$ P(X_1 = 1,X_2 = 3) = P(X_1-X_0 = 1, X_2-X_1 = 2).$$

Then use the property that $X_1-X_0$ and $X_2-X_1$ are independent Poisson RVs. (*Not* $X_2$ and $X_1$... reread the definition.)

Answer (score 2):

If you have 3 events in the interval $(0,2)$ and $1$ event in the interval $(0,1)$ then you can conclude that you have $2$ events in the interval (1,2).

Therefore the required probability is

$$\underbrace{2^1\frac{e^{-2}}{1!}}_{\text{interval} (0,1)}\cdot \underbrace{2^2\frac{e^{-2}}{2!}}_{\text{interval} (1,2)}=4\cdot e^{-4}$$

Comment: Oh what a nice way to see the solution of the problem. Thanks

Comment: I´m glad to hear that. You´re welcome.